# O que significa o parâmetro crossDomain:false em Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Estou implementando um aplicativo web de upload de imagens em `Ajax` e existe o parâmetro `crossDomain:false` em um exemplo encontrando. Qual a função desse parâmetro?

Comment: Cross: cruzar, domain: domínio. Cruzar domínios, imagine como se fosse a interação entre dois domínios diferentes.

Comment: Se você for buscar um ficheiro que está num outro domínio, isso chama-se "cross domain".

Comment: @Sergio Entendi, mas há a necessidade de colocar `crossDomain:false`? O padrão é `true`? Não entendi bem a diferença na prática desse parâmetro, se eu deixar `true` por padrão vai trazer algum malefício ou isso é apenas para explicitar algo?

Comment: @Orion se colocar aqui o link para esse plugin/opção podemos ver no código fonte a que se refere o "crossDomain".

Comment: @Sergio no final da página contém o código https://github.com/sigurdga/django-jquery-file-upload/blob/master/fileupload/templates/fileupload/picture_basic_form.html

Comment: @Orion, ok. E vendo mais acima encontro o url do plugin `fileUpload`. Eu estou sem tempo agora, mas dê uma olhada aqui (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) e coloque a resposta. Se não faço eu ou alguém depois.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No conceito do JQuery, o parâmetro `crossDomain:false` define o comportamento caso redirecionamentos entre domínios ocorram na página chamada pelo método. Por exemplo:

- `www.dominio.com/pagina.html` invoca método Ajax: `www.dominio.com/servico.ashx`.
- `www.dominio.com/servico.ashx` retorna HTTP `302 Found` apontando para `shop.dominio.com/servico.ashx`.

Caso `crossDomain:false`, essa chamada Ajax falha automaticamente.

Caso `crossDomain:true`, essa chamada Ajax é permitida.