# O que significa Cross-Domain?

Tags: aplicação-web, cross-domain

Procurando sobre o assunto, ouvi dizer que `Cross-Domain` é uma interação entre domínios diferentes. Inclusive, encontrei uma pergunta semelhante no próprio SOPT, conforme link abaixo. Entretanto, o conceito em si não ficou claro na minha visão, pois apesar das perguntas serem semelhantes, o conteúdo/enfoque delas é diferente.

[O que significa o parâmetro crossDomain:false em Ajax?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25877/o-que-%C3%A9-cross-domain)

Afinal, conceitualmente falando, o que é `Cross-Domain` ?

Comment: você já leu o que diz na tag "cross-domain", aqui mesmo no stackoverflow?
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cross-domain

Comment: acabei de ler, deixa eu ver se entendi, eu tenho minha página neste endereço "http://www.teste.com/enviar.html" , e faço uma requisição para uma página "http://www.aplicacao.com.br/requisitado.html" , isso que é o cross-domain?

Comment: basicamente, sim

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## `Cross-Domain`

Em uma página web, quando a janela pai contém um `iFrame` filho que está apontando para outro domínio, não há absolutamente nenhuma maneira de acessar o conteúdo desse `iFrame` filho. Por sua vez, o `iFrame` filho não pode acessar qualquer conteúdo da janela pai. Por conteúdo, quero dizer, usando algo parecido com o `document.getElementId('frameid').forms[0]` para obter uma referência a algum elemento, como um formulário. Existe apenas uma exceção a isso. Se dois domínios diferentes diferem somente em seu domínio sub-. Você pode usar JavaScript para definir os domínios dos frames para o domínio principal e, em seguida, os frames serão capazes de acessar o conteúdo de cada um.

Se os frames estão no mesmo domínio e, então os frames podem aceder um ao outro. Para fazer isso, você deve obter uma referência para o elemento `iFrame` geralmente por meio do `getElementId('frameid')`. Então, existem duas maneiras de acessar o objeto da janela pelo o `iFrame`. A maneira antes do `IE8` e a maneira normal.

```
function getIframeWindow(iframeElement){
    return iframeElement.contentWindow || iframeElement.contentDocument.parentWindow;
}
```

`contentWindow` é o que era fornecido pelos navegadores antes do `IE8`. `contentDocument.parentWindow` é o que existe nos navegadores modernos. Você pode então usar essa referência para manipular o `DOM` do `iFrame` tal como faria na janela principal.

**Alguns resources sobre isso:**

- [content document](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentdocument.asp)
- [iFrames](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/09/15/iframes-onload-and-documentdomain/)

### Comunicação entre frames em domínios diferentes

Então a única coisa útil que realmente pode ocorrer entre 2 frames em domínios diferentes é a comunicação, um quadro enviando uma mensagem para outro quadro. Há muitas maneiras de fazer isso, mas a única certeza é que ambos os domínios tem que estar ciente do contrato de comunicação. Caso contrário, um frame enviaria uma mensagem para um outro e seria ignorado. Ou um frame estaria ouvindo uma mensagem nunca seria enviada.

### Comunicação entre domínios com servers diferentes

Ao fazer uma solicitação `HTTP` em uma `web page` de um domínio para um servidor em outro domínio, as regras ainda são as mesmas: ambos os domínios tem que estar ciente do contrato de comunicação. Se ambos os domínios não concordar em enviar e aceitar um formato de mensagem, nada pode acontecer. Por exemplo: não é possível fazer um `request` para `http://www.google.com (home page)` com qualquer uma das seguintes técnicas e usar a informação que é recebida, porque o site `www.google.com` não está programado para saber sobre qualquer cliente específico que faz o pedido.

#### Form Posting

A maneira mais básica de enviar uma solicitação para um servidor a partir de um web site é através de um `form post`. É possível com o JavaScript adicionar programaticamente um `iFrame` para a janela pai. Nesse `iFrame`, você pode adicionar um formulário que aponta para outro domínio. Nesse form, você pode adicionar uma série de `hidden inputs` que representam a informação que você quer que seja enviada para o domínio. Você pode então enviar o form que irá fazer uma solicitação `POST` para esse domínio.

Há um pequeno problema com isso. Quando o `iFrame` receber a resposta do outro domínio, restrições do site irão negar outro acesso e você não vai pode mais acessar o frame para obter qualquer informação que foi enviada de volta. Se você simplesmente precisa enviar informações, essa técnica resolve.

#### `JavaScript (JSONP)`

`JSONP` é limitado na medida em que só pode fazer requisições `GET`, não mensagens. Não há nenhuma maneira de um navegador fazer um `POST` para uma tag script. Além disso, arquivos de script em outro domínio não podem definir cookies para esse domínio.

#### `Ajax`

`Ajax` permite que você faça `request` assíncrona para o navegador. Mas esta técnica é a mais exigente para fazer a comunicação de cross domain. Por padrão, você não pode fazer uma solicitação Ajax para um domínio diferente da janela que é feita. A fim de fazer isso, você deve usar uma técnica chamada `CORS`. Este é um padrão oficial que está se tornando mais consistente em todos os navegadores.

Mais uma vez, o mesmo princípio aplica-se aqui. Tanto o cliente e o servidor deve ter conhecimento um do outro, para que o canal de comunicação seja estabelecido. `Ajax CORS` tem uma vantagem sobre `JSONP`, em que ele pode fazer solicitações `POST` e o `JSONP` não.

### Exemplos de `Cross Domain`

- Você tem que se integrar com um serviço de terceiros (como um fórum) que tem uma API REST residente em uma origem diferente.
- Seus `server-side services` são hospedados em diferentes (sub) domínios.
- Sua lógica `client-side` é servida a partir de uma origem diferente do que seus `endpoints` lado do servidor.